# Why does my asyncio event loop die when I kill a forked subprocess (PTY)?

Tags: python, subprocess, python-asyncio, fastapi, pty

I try to create a software that spawns bash shells and makes them controllable via websockets.

It's based on fastapi and fastapi_socketio on the server side and socket.io + JS on the client side.

Gotta admit that I am an absolute noob when it comes down to asyncio. I can use it when I control it by myself but I am not familiar with managing event loops etc. coming from other modules.

To start a PTY I use the [fork()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pty.html#pty.fork) method from the pty module like in figure "1 - Forking a PTY" (the submitted command is "/bin/bash"):

It actually works pretty well. The client_sid is the socket.io session id of the client and I can seamlessly control multiple terminals via xtermjs from my web UI.

I got one problem though. When I issue "exit" into xtermjs, I expect the child process to exit and free the file descriptor. This should be detected by the fstat method in the method displayed in figure "2 - The method sending the PTYs STDOUT/ERR to the remote socket" and the method should just exit and close the websocket connection then.

What happens instead is that the web terminal receives multiple exceptions in a very fast manner (figure "3 - The error displayed to the client") and when I try to shut down uvicorn with CTRL+C I get the error from figure "4 - The error displayed when I try to shutdown uvicorn with CTRL+C".

I'd really appreciate any help with this topic because I just don't have deep enough knowledge of asynchronous python (and probably the OS/PTYs) yet.

To me it feels like the child process forked from my main process is somehow interacting with the asyncio loops but I really don't know how. Is the child process probably inheriting the asyncio loop and killing it when it dies, does that make any sense?

The only solution coming to my mind is detecting the "kill" command issued from the web UI but that would miss e.g. a kill signal sent to the PTY subprocess and it's not really clean.

Thanks in regard.

1 - Forking a PTY

```
async def pty_handle_pty_config(self, sio: AsyncServer, client_sid: str, message: dict):
    
    if not client_sid in self.clients or self.clients[client_sid] is None:
        await self.disconnect_client(sio=sio, client_sid=client_sid)
        return

    if not isinstance(message, dict) or not 'command' in message or not isinstance(message['command'], str):
        await self.disconnect_client(sio=sio, client_sid=client_sid)
        return

    child_pid, fd = fork() # pty.fork()
    if child_pid == 0:
        subproc_run(message['command']) # subprocess.run()
    else:
        self.ptys[client_sid] = {
            'fd': fd
        }
        self.set_winsize(client_sid, 50, 50)
        await sio.emit('pty_begin', data=dict(state='success'), namespace='/pty', room=client_sid)
        sio.start_background_task(
            target=self.pty_read_and_forward,
            sio=sio,
            client_sid=client_sid,
            client_data=self.clients[client_sid]
        )
```

2 - The method sending the PTYs STDOUT/ERR to the remote socket

```
async def pty_read_and_forward(self, sio: AsyncServer, client_sid: str, client_data: dict):
    log = get_logger()
    max_read_bytes = 1024 * 20
    loop = get_event_loop()
    while True:
        try:
            await async_sleep(.05) # asyncio.sleep
            timeout_sec = 0
            (data_ready, _, _) = await loop.run_in_executor(None, select, [self.ptys[client_sid]['fd']], [], [], timeout_sec) 
            if data_ready:
                output = await loop.run_in_executor(None, os_read, self.ptys[client_sid]['fd'], max_read_bytes) # os.read
                try:
                    fstat(self.ptys[client_sid]['fd']) # os.fstat
                except OSError as exc:
                    log.error(exc)
                    break
                await sio.emit(
                    event='pty_out',
                    data=dict(
                        output=output.decode('utf-8', errors='ignore')
                    ),
                    namespace='/pty',
                    room=client_sid
                )
        except Exception as exc:
            if not client_sid in self.clients:
                log.info(f'PTY session closed [sid={client_sid};user={client_data["username"]}]')
            else:
                log.warn(f'PTY session closed unexpectedly [sid={client_sid};user={client_data["username"]}] - {excstr(exc)}')
            break
```

3 - The error displayed to the client

```
asyncio.exceptions.CancelledError

Process SpawnProcess-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/process.py", line 314, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/uvicorn/_subprocess.py", line 76, in subprocess_started
    target(sockets=sockets)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/uvicorn/server.py", line 60, in run
    return asyncio.run(self.serve(sockets=sockets))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 646, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/uvicorn/server.py", line 80, in serve
    await self.main_loop()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/uvicorn/server.py", line 221, in main_loop
    await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/tasks.py", line 599, in sleep
    loop = events.get_running_loop()
RuntimeError: no running event loop
```

4 - The error displayed when I try to shutdown uvicorn with CTRL+C

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/unix_events.py", line 42, in _sighandler_noop
    def _sighandler_noop(signum, frame):
BlockingIOError: [Errno 11] Resource temporarily unavailable
```

Answer (score 0):

I luckily got the problem fixed by invoking os.execvpe() instead of using subprocess.run(). This approach replaces the child process with a completely new process while staying connected to the file descriptor the parent process is able to read.

I didn't really know the consequences of using fork() in the child when asyncio is used within the parent process. It's a really bad approach because asyncio won't be able to separate the child's event loop from the parent one. If you close the child one's, the parent's one will also stop working due to both "sharing" their environment thanks to the fork().

See this question for more details: [mixing asyncio with fork in python: bad idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63576534/mixing-asyncio-with-fork-in-python-bad-idea)

It works like this:

```
child_pid, fd = fork()
if child_pid == 0:
    # This is the forked process. Replace it with the command
    # the user wants to run.
    env = os.environ.copy()
    execvpe(message['command'], [message['command'],], env)
```